# Problem with Authorize of a Private Web API when I try to use GET Method

Tags: api, get, webapi

I need to use this web api (https://api.sandbox.urbaner.com/api/client/order_types/) powered by 'Urbaner'. My personal token for this Api is 'df9ec639b04913a6cf113fdfbb8dfac02e25eab0'

The Urbaner documentation for Get Method it this

Example request
$ curl -X GET \ 
  https://api.sandbox.urbaner.com/api/client/order_types/ \
  -H 'authorization: token YOUR_TOKEN'
Example response
{
  "num_pages": 1,
  "next": null,
  "count": 3,
  "previous": null,
  "current_page": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "code": "EXP",
      "name": "EXPRESS",
      "image": "https://urbaner-delivery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/package_types/express_SBfPdqd.png",
      "max_points": 100,
      "allow_return": true,
      "allow_programed_pickup": true,
      "allow_programed_dropoff": false,
      "allow_massiver_order": false
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "code": "SDAY",
      "name": "SAMEDAY",
      "image": "https://urbaner-delivery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/package_types/sameday_PtjNUpX.png",
      "max_points": 2,
      "allow_return": false,
      "allow_programed_pickup": false,
      "allow_programed_dropoff": false,
      "allow_massiver_order": true
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "code": "NDAY",
      "name": "NEXTDAY",
      "image": "https://urbaner-delivery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/package_types/nextday_ImhFLpE.png",
      "max_points": 2,
      "allow_return": false,
      "allow_programed_pickup": false,
      "allow_programed_dropoff": true,
      "allow_massiver_order": true
    }
  ]
}

#### I dont know how put in POSTMAN the header 'authorize' o whatever for my personal account token of this web api and get the right response in this GET method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a get request using postman using your token id and attached a screenshot with this comment.
Download postman software and follow the same you will be able to make requests too.
**Steps :** 
 1. Paste the url in the url link in the link bar as in the image.
 2. Use headers tab and add authorization header in the same format as picture.
 3. Now push the send button that's it.

[image: Postman Screenshot]